# What's the point of a cache on the swap space?

Tags: memory, caching, buffer, swap

Isn't the point of caching things in main memory to avoid the expensive disk i/o?

If you're caching things in the swap space of a hard drive, how does that avoid disk i/o?

Comment: What system are you talking about? Why do you believe that this systems caches the swap space?

Answer (score 4):

Generally the memory used by the cache wouldn't get swapped out.
It would be marked as in-use.

edit - Yes virtual memory is memory blocks copied to disk because the RAM is full. In order to use it you have to copy it back into memory (which is slow).
Cache is keeping copies of recently used files in memory because this is quicker than going back to disk for them.  There is a conflict here - the more RAM you use for cache, the more other memory you have to swap out to disk, assuming you have none free left.
This isn't necessarily bad, there are lots of things running on your computer that only run occaisonally and so pushing them out to disk to make space for cached copies of your photos might make sense.

Comment: ah, so the swap space is just to support virtual memory, and not so much to improve performance, correct?

Comment: Yes. (obligatory minimum comment length text here)

Comment: It can improve performance by freeing memory to be used by caches.

Comment: Can it slow performance if my data is on an SSD and my swap on a spinning hard disk?